# How to specify return type of a promise in typescript based on the input type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a "rollup" service in TypeScript that can save an object based on it's type, but TypeScript is telling me I'm doing something illegal (`TS2322`).

Here's a simplified version of my code; first I have an enum which describes all the object classes that I have:

```
enum ThingType {
    SomeThing = 'SomeThing',
    OtherThing = 'OtherThing',
}
```

Then there's an interface that describes the base type, as well as a couple of derived types:

```
interface IThing {
    name: string;
    type: ThingType;
}

interface ISomeThing extends IThing {
    // properties of ISomeThing
}

interface IOtherThing extends IThing {
    // properties of IOtherThing
}
```

For each derived type, there's a specific service that saves objects of those types:

```
function saveSomeThing(someThing: ISomeThing): Promise<ISomeThing> {
    return Promise.resolve(someThing);
}

function saveOtherThing(otherThing: IOtherThing): Promise<IOtherThing> {
    return Promise.resolve(otherThing);
}
```

#### The problem

Now I want to have a single "rollup" service that delegates the save operation to the correct implementation:

```
function saveThing<T extends IThing>(thing: T): Promise<T> {
    switch (thing.type) {
        case ThingType.SomeThing: return saveSomeThing(thing as ISomeThing);
        case ThingType.OtherThing: return saveOtherThing(thing as IOtherThing);
        default: throw new Error('Unknown type: ' + thing.type);
    }
}
```

TypeScript tells me that my `return` statements are invalid:

```
TS2322: Type 'Promise<ISomeThing>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T>'.
   Type 'ISomeThing' is not assignable to type 'T'.
     'ISomeThing' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IThing'.
```

That's fair enough - TypeScript doesn't know that `T` will be an `ISomeThing` for that branch of the `switch` - is there a way I can tell TypeScript that it is (without resorting to an `unknown` or `any`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

## Marking your return with `as any`(you don't lose any type information since the function itself is typed)

> Mostly here since the other way is rather cumbersome and does not add any real value:

```
function saveThing<T extends IThing>(thing: T): Promise<T> {
    switch (thing.type) {
        case ThingType.SomeThing: return saveSomeThing(thing as ISomeThing) as any;
        case ThingType.OtherThing: return saveOtherThing(thing as IOtherThing) as any;
        default: throw new Error('Unknown type: ' + thing.type);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgFgSxAcxgTwA7CgbwFBSFQDKA9hMPEsgDQFEDyALnMAE5Up4C+eeSTdgDMAhgGNsASU7Jc9QiBEUAXFADOTNtQDc8qE0zBVM9Fl29+IQW1ESokshRlRgAD0EgAJmvvP8RfUNjRBRTYAA6R0oQ5HM+AWFxKWZWDhiXd1BvX3T-IgMsYOow8JT2GTi8ITAQMSYEUhB1EQA3YCiZAAo1cmjqVQdemQBKVQAFNnIENWAAHkGnGIA+OQC2YCYwNiaJqZnw9Z6AGzbuoZjhyura+sbmtrK06k7SFnKYgceR8cmIabnJF9lqsiOtNtsoLs-vtDqQTsAXm8nihLjw+Nc6g0mmpWn0ULMYBkPNlpMtOix+rBRpDfv8CSs8oQ1AB3BBMMRwKDkmLhArAYYggKEMQiGawGIlDofKBgrbY3FS54UlBQUX2RUo1U+EQgNC6IVEEVikyGUpImSqWUQnEPc0xbnULX2IHUAVqnV6vQBTzAURgI5MVQsSbMqAgYChgCibEmbE6AHIAKogADWIFIzKafNU8agAGp9Dy+aiArxuEA)

## Using a type guard function and a conditional return type

```
function saveThing<T extends IThing>(thing: T): Promise<T extends ISomeThing ? ISomeThing : IOtherThing> {
    type returnType = T extends ISomeThing ? ISomeThing : IOtherThing;
    if(isISomeThing(thing)){
        return saveSomeThing(thing) as Promise<returnType>;
    }
    if(isIOtherThing(thing)){
        return saveOtherThing(thing) as Promise<returnType>;
    }

    throw new Error('Unknown type: ' + thing.type);

    function isISomeThing(potentialISomeThing: IThing): potentialISomeThing is ISomeThing {
        return potentialISomeThing.type === ThingType.SomeThing;
    }
    function isIOtherThing(potentialIOtherThing: IThing): potentialIOtherThing is IOtherThing {
        return potentialIOtherThing.type === ThingType.OtherThing;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=58&pln=27&pc=104#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgFgSxAcxgTwA7CgbwFBSFQDKA9hMPEsgDQFEDyALnMAE5Up4C+eeSTdgDMAhgGNsASU7Jc9QiBEUAXFADOTNtQDc8qE0zBVM9Fl29+IQW1ESokshRlRgAD0EgAJmvvP8RfUNjRBRTYAA6R0oQ5HM+AWFxKWZWDhiXd1BvX3T-IgMsYOow8JT2GTi8ITAQMSYEUhB1EQA3YCiZAAo1cmjqVQdemQBKVQAFNnIENWAAHkGnGIA+OQC2YCYwNiaJqZnw9Z6AGzbuoZjhyura+sbmtrK06k7SFnKYgceR8cmIabnJF9lqsiOtNtsoLs-vtDqQTsAXm8nihLjw+Nc6g0mmpWn0ULMYBkPNlpMtOix+rBRpDfv8CUSsj4FnjZAB+ewddKfJEyFZ5QgFbBgrYgMJQAC8sAZXiZnOoUHZzOc3NSFT0CCEnWmSpi5Iuw35ASgwohOLacpQeuowygIh8ULpJtFhiWugCvACGq1akBPN1FJRBr0aw2IvuwCBzwDyBtdppezmTrCrr0FgCLEmAHcoCBgNmAKJsSZsToAcgAqiAANYgUiZpqC1SlqAAan0MXCgtRegxtya2otyE6GFeoHqIiOOsppOtqhHHnHk8HUGmHPO8sNIfBTXnY4QE6nKE7hgl4slJkMkXXKDdRA9RF7WJXPsjlt3Vn3k9fyAG3yg78XX1VXSVcgPeDdg1BUMIQAz8wORZBjywU9zxiEpv1vQheG4IA)

Comment: Looks like the `any` approach will be best - there's about 13 different types in the actual code so the conditional return type would become even _more_ cumbersome. Thanks!